# How to change the style class of a certain div

Tags: drupal, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-theming

I'm a novice trying to learn basics for fun.
I've set up a 7.24 drupal website. I've installed the bootstrap theme. I managed to create a subtheme and activated it. I use the bootstrap-cdn method.

Now, I'm not happy with the style of certain elements. Bootstrap already has great css definitions but they are not used in the basic starter kit of the theme.

**So here's my problem:**
I want the tag fields of my articles to be styled with the style class `label label-info` of bootstrap - displayed here:

[image: bootstrap label label-info]

I've read an article about the usage of template.php but I'm stuck for hours to find the right method name. Something like `<mythemename>_field_X_X_X()`. How do I find out which method name I have to use?

If there is an easier way to change/add the style of a certain div class I'm open for suggestions.

Thank you for reading this! Your help is appreciated.

Comment: So basically, you want to add a css class on a tag (term) that you can define in the CMS ?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module [Semantic fields](https://drupal.org/project/semantic_fields) did the job.